# JMSType is coming as null in activeMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using activeMq and set the jms type using 'setJMSType' api .

```
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Hello, this is my first message.");
message.setJMSType("Advisory");
```

But, When try to get the jms type (using 'getJMSType' API) at consumer end, I am getitng null.

**Other Information**

ActiveMQ Version: 5.15.3

JMS Domain : Point-To-Point (Queue)

Reference
http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-message-properties.html

Comment: Provide more details, versions etc.

Comment: Hi Tim, updated the information in problem description

Comment: There are multiple tests in the ActiveMQ code for this and they work fine so without any other information it is hard to know what you are doing wrong, perhaps there are other messages still in that Queue that lack a type value

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the information. I see some pending messages in the queue. It is because of that.